# is there a way to optimize this sql server query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 3 tables:

**Table1**:

```
id   |   name
1    |   joe
2    |   peter
3    |   sandra
```

**Table2**:

```
id   |   fkId   |   date_updated
1    |    1     |   2013-01-31
2    |    1     |   2013-04-01
3    |    2     |   2013-02-04
4    |    2     |   2013-01-02
```

**Table3**:

```
id   |   fkId   |   date_updated
1    |    1     |   2013-01-31
2    |    3     |   2013-04-01
3    |    3     |   2013-02-04
4    |    2     |   2013-01-02
```

I have the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     table3 ON table1.id = table3.fkId
GROUP BY 
     table1.id
HAVING 
     table2.date_updated = max(table2.date_updated)
     AND table3.date_updated = max(table3.date_updated)
```

My output looks like this:

```
 name |   table2   |  table3  
joe   | 2013-04-01 | 2013-01-31
peter | 2013-02-04 | 2013-01-02
sandra|            | 2013-04-01
```

I get the data I need but this query takes too long, is there anyway to optimize it without modifying the table indices?

Things to point out:

- table2 and table3 are not the same table.
- I need to get the entire row that was "last_updated" from table2 and table3, not just the date.

EDIT **

Query is taking around 3-4 secs when using a `WHERE table1.id = id` , to return a single record.

Table1 has ~ 84000 recs

Table2 has ~ 96000 recs

Table3 has ~ 81000 recs

Comment: An index on table2.date_updated and table3.date_updated *might* help. But your best bet is always to look at the execution plan.

Comment: You mention WITHOUT modifying the indexes, however, without listing what the indexes are, we can't necessarily advise more.  I would have an index on both tables by (id, date_updated)

Comment: @DRapp There are only indexes on the `id` not the `date_updated` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data as presented, the query is seems to be:

```
SELECT table1.name, MAX(table2.date_updated), MAX(table3.date_updated)
FROM  table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      table2
      ON table1.id = table2.fkId LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      table3 ON table1.id = table3.fkId
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Indexes on `table2(fkid, date_updated)` and table3(fkid, date_updated)` might help.

Actually, with such indexes, this version will probably have better performance:

```
select table1.name,
       (select date_updated from table2 where table1.id = table2.fkid order by date_updated desc limit 1
       ) as T2,
       (select date_updated from table3 where table1.id = table3.fkid order by date_updated desc limit 1
       ) as T3
from table1
```

This eliminates the grouping entirely, replacing it with a correlated subquery -- and the correlated subquery should turn into an index small index scan.

Comment: The first one would not work for me since I'm looking for the entire row that has the `max(date)`; however, the second query you provided helped me re-write the query and it now returns in ~0.2 secs, instead of the 3-4 secs from before. By using the second query there was no need to add any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned without modifying the indexes, but what you are trying to do would only be more optimized if you had each "Table2" and "Table3" to have indexes on

( fkId, date_updated ).

If you only have an index on each table's "ID" column, then obviously nothing will be optimized on the join.  You would need it on the foreign key to Table1 at a minimum.  But since this would be a NEW index on the table, it should not hurt anything, but only HELP your queries.  Do this index on BOTH Table2 and Table3.

Comment: So having an index on `fkId` only, for table2 and table3 would not help this query, correct?

Comment: It would help, but not as much as (fkID, date_updated).  Most of the time, it can benefit having a multiple field index based on a key AND some other column(s) that will be a typical query condition basis.  If the query only needs the FK, no problem, it can still utilize the index.  If it can utilize BOTH fields, even better.  Nothing lost if just querying on FK.